# grunt-cli doesn't work with docker volume mounted, fine without

Tags: gruntjs, docker

I set up an angular development environment using the following Dockerfile (don't try to build this unless you're really enthusiastic, it takes an age).

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# build environment
RUN ["apt-get", "update"]
RUN ["apt-get", "install", "-y", "nodejs", "npm", "git"]
RUN ["ln", "-s", "/usr/bin/nodejs", "/usr/bin/node"]
RUN ["npm", "install", "-g", "yo"]
RUN ["npm", "install", "-g", "bower"]
RUN ["npm", "install", "-g", "grunt-cli"]

WORKDIR /home/angular
ADD ./package.json /home/angular/package.json
ADD ./bower.json /home/angular/bower.json
ADD ./dist /home/angular/dist

RUN ["npm", "install"]
RUN ["bower", "install", "--allow-root"]

# sass depedencies
ENV RUBY_MAJOR 2.2
ENV RUBY_VERSION 2.2.2
ENV RUBY_DOWNLOAD_SHA256 5ffc0f317e429e6b29d4a98ac521c3ce65481bfd22a8cf845fa02a7b113d9b44

# some of ruby's build scripts are written in ruby
# we purge this later to make sure our final image uses what we just built
RUN ["apt-get", "install", "-y", "curl"]
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y autoconf bison libgdbm-dev ruby \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && mkdir -p /usr/src/ruby \
    && curl -fSL -o ruby.tar.gz "http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/$RUBY_MAJOR/ruby-$RUBY_VERSION.tar.gz" \
    && echo "$RUBY_DOWNLOAD_SHA256 *ruby.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c - \
    && tar -xzf ruby.tar.gz -C /usr/src/ruby --strip-components=1 \
    && rm ruby.tar.gz \
    && cd /usr/src/ruby \
    && autoconf \
    && ./configure --disable-install-doc \
    && make -j"$(nproc)" \
    && make install \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove bison libgdbm-dev ruby \
    && rm -r /usr/src/ruby

# skip installing gem documentation
RUN echo 'gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri' >> "$HOME/.gemrc"

# install things globally, for great justice
ENV GEM_HOME /usr/local/bundle
ENV PATH $GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH

ENV BUNDLER_VERSION 1.10.5

RUN gem install bundler --version "$BUNDLER_VERSION" \
    && bundle config --global path "$GEM_HOME" \
    && bundle config --global bin "$GEM_HOME/bin"

# don't create ".bundle" in all our apps
ENV BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG $GEM_HOME

RUN gem install compass

VOLUME ["/home/me/code/correspondence/client/dist"]

ADD ./ /home/angular
```

If I run this with:

```
sudo docker run -it me/angular /bin/bash
```

I can use `grunt build` with no problems. Since I haven't attached a volume to `dist` that build is no use to other containers such as the webserver. But running:

```
sudo docker run -itv /home/me/code/correspondence/client/dist:/home/angular me/angular /bin/bash
```

results in the `grunt build` command no longer being usable in the container:

```
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.13)

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or grunt
hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more information about
installing and configuring grunt, please see the Getting Started guide:

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
```

The only difference is adding the volume. How does adding the volume result in this different behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that's because you have placed some files to `/home/angular` in image and when you're mounting your volume to the same path (`/home/angular`), your volume hides original files.

Quote from [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/):

> Note: If the path `/opt/webapp` already exists inside the container’s
>   image, its contents will be replaced by the contents of `/src/webapp` on
>   the host to stay consistent with the expected behavior of mount

Try to mount volume to another directory, `/home/angular/dist/client`, for instance.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said in the question that adding `VOLUME` into the Dockerfile was something I tried to see if it would help, but I get the same behaviour either way. I think I might have tracked down the problem and, if I get time today, I'll confirm what caused it and post here.